# Understanding patch for my report

Tags: encryption, web-application, cryptography, token, uuid

I reported a flaw to the security team and they changed the UIDs from regular integers to hash kind of a thing. Like this, XXXX-XXXX-and-so-on

I still want to try and bypass things but I don't understand what kind of hashing is this? I have seen a lot of applications using this kind of hash for tokens, UIDs etc. Characters are separated by `-` (dash or a hyphen) in these kind of tokens.

Comment: This question is missing essential context. Basically you only say that they fixed a vulnerability by making some changes you want to bypass again - without really saying what the vulnerability was and what mitigations they exactly implemented. One can only guess that "integer" means that they had a predictable part in the URL (i.e. enumeration possible) and *"hash kind of thing"* means no longer predictable to you.

Comment: It's quite tough to explain compete flaw here as I chained multiple things but yes you are right the crux is integers were guessable while this hash kind of thing isn't. I want to understand if its really something with high entropy or not so that I can find a way to guess or predict.

Comment: But for that I have to first figure out what kind of token this is.

Answer (score 3):

That is probably a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or GUID. It looks like this:

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
              ^
```

There are several versions, indicated by the mark above. Version 4 is random. Version 1 and 2 are not random, so these may still be predictable and useful in an insecure direct object reference.

While GUID's may be hard to guess, it is still considered best practice to also check authorisation. So even if you have the GUID of another user's object, you still shouldn't be able to access it.